# Dynamic angular pagination depending on value length

Tags: angular, dynamic, paginator

I need help with the Angular 12 paginator.
I would like to make the number of elements per page dynamic, so that based on the length of the values sometimes more and sometimes less elements are displayed per page.

The implementation was done with mat-table and mat-paginator in a mat-dialog.

A keyword would be enough for me, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: For pagination in API, it should have 2 keys/parameters. 
1. Page: 1, 2, 3, ... 
2. Limit: 10, 20, 50, 100

With both you have a good pagination and also no further key requires. Backend developer will know that skip is (Page=2(-1) x Limit=10 = 10) so backend developer will skip 10 results and show you next 10 results easily.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **pageSize** as input on mat-paginator. In this you can specify the length.

As pageSize is an input binding, it gets updated in the view as we update in the ts.

In the component ts file, you can set pageSize wherever you want.

For ie

```
 this.pageSize= value.length;
```

HTML

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="pageEvent = $event"
               aria-label="Select page">
</mat-paginator>
```

For more info, please visit the below given Offical API website: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess I expressed myself a little badly. I'll upload my example to Stackblitz in a moment so I can explain it a bit more.

Comment: Maybe not the best work, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to show everything from the code.

But you can already see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ifmswa?file=src/index.html).

I would like to have it so that the paginator does not move at the bottom and the page is always filled as far as it can go.